# Best xxcopy flags for one-time drive mirror/clone?

Tags: windows, mirroring, cloning, xxcopy

I’ve settled on [xxcopy](http://www.xxcopy.com/) to do a one-time clone/mirror to my NAS before the source drive is reformatted.

Due to the amount of data and the desire not to impact daytime home usage, it’ll be run as a scheduled task from 11pm-6am over the course of many days. I would use robocopy, but it doesn’t verify files.

The xxcopy documentation is massive but I think I’ve narrowed it down to:

```
xxcopy /clone /v2 <source> <destination>
```

Are there any other flags I should consider? Accuracy is more important than speed.

Comment: My weapon of choice would either be free file sync (you setup a task, and you can either run it in monitoring mode (every change is synced) or schedule it to run. It has version control too, which is a great protection against cryptolocker) or alternatively, TeraCopy is great too. You may also want to consider an actual backup solution, such as Veeam (free). That way you can schedule active hours and have incremental backups with occasional full backups. You don't have a mirror/clone though, but restoring is easy.

Comment: Cobian Backup can do this too, I believe.

Comment: Based on your edit, I still stand by my 2 choices, though TeraCopy is probably the best option here. They can't really schedule the copy natively, but they can pause/resume. You could even use robocopy to do the initial copy, then use TeraCopy to verify that the copy was done succesfully, and when failed, use TeraCopy to copy everything that failed (native function of TeraCopy, work with failed files) Reason of failure: file does not exist, filesize is different, file has changed and a newer copy is there, etc... Also, TeraCopy has a nifty UI, so no command line options necessary.

Comment: @LPChip Thanks, I looked at terracopy and the command line options were limited and I need to schedule the copy when everyone is sleeping. Robocopy and then terracopy to verify might be a better way.

Comment: One more thing, With TeraCopy, to verify files, Make the copy as normal, it will popup that the files exist and what you want to do, select skip all. It will walk through all files. After that is finished, run a test (verify) to verify all files. Once done you can remove all succesfully transferred files. Either your list is now empty, all went well, or errors remain. After your list is small with only errors, you can copy them again directly from TeraCopy, or go through the list manually.

Comment: @LPChip Very useful, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I do not have sufficient knowledge of xxcopy to provide you with an answer on how to use that specific tool, but based on our comments exchange, I feel that I can still write you an acceptable answer.

Given that you know how to use RoboCopy, my suggestion is to setup everything using RoboCopy and use TeraCopy to verify the files after the copy was done succesfully. Of course, TeraCopy is not the only tool you can use to verify the files, but I have found out that TeraCopy is an extremely powerful and fast tool, especially since you can immediately fix problems after the verify, and once you get to know TeraCopy, you may even switch to it as it can verify files by default after each copy.

**How to verify files with TeraCopy?**

In order to verify files with TeraCopy, copy the files with TeraCopy first. If you install TeraCopy, it is as easy as just using a windows copy/paste and let TeraCopy handle the copy. You can also do it manually by dragging the files into TeraCopy and selecting its destination from the GUI.

Once you are ready to copy the files with TeraCopy, it will notice that the files already exists and asks you what to do. Select here to Skip all. TeraCopy will now attempt to copy the files, skipping everything (unless new files were added, it will copy those) and mark everything else as skipped.

Once done, it allows you to verify/test the current list. This is what you are after. The list will have one checkmark before succesful copied files, and an arrow to the right for skipped files. Once a file is verified, it changes to 2 checkmarks and turns blue.

Anything that is not exactly the same will show up as an error.

Once the verification is done, remove all succesfully transferred files. Either your list is now empty (all was succesful) or a few errors remain.

You can see why they failed and attempt to copy them again, or manaully work with the files.